# If we know that $A\equiv x\pmod{M}$, can we know what $x\pmod{m}$ is for any other $m$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given two integers $A$ and $M$ such that $A = x \pmod {M}$ where $x$ is an unknown integer.

Is it possible to find out the answer for $x \pmod {m}$ where $m$ is any other given number ?

Comment: It's possible if $m$ divides $M$. You can constrain the candidates if the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $M$ is $> 1$. But if $m > 1$ is coprime to $M$, any remainder modulo $m$ is possible.

Comment: @DanielFischer will you please explain clearly if M is any prime number and if m is any integer then how can we find ?

Comment: If $m = 1$, then the remainder `x % m` is $0$. That's trivial. Otherwise, if $M$ is prime, and $m < M$ (more generally, if $m$ is not a multiple of $M$), you know _nothing_ about `x % m`. If $m$ is a multiple of $M$, and $x \equiv B \pmod{m}$, then you know that $B \equiv A \pmod{M}$, which constrains the possibilities, there are $\frac{m}{M}$.

Comment: okay that means its impossible to get the answer if M is not divisible by m

Answer (score 1):

If $m$ is a divisor of $M$, then $A \equiv x (\mod M)$ implies that $A \equiv x (\mod m)$.

That is, if $A = x \% M$, then $A \% m = x \% m$.

Comment: and if M is not divisible by m then ? e.g M is any prime number.

Comment: Then you can't find it for certain. As mentioned in Daniel's comment on your question, if $m$ and $M$ are not coprime, there are some restrictions you can get, but unless $m$ divides $M$, there is no way to find a single result.